# jQuery reload div on button click

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to reload a div (`#parent`) when I click on a button (`#button`). That div contains an external PHP file. The problem I have is that it only works once when clicked.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
HTML
<div id="parent"> 
    <?php include 'content.php'; ?>
</div>

jQuery
$(function () {
    $("#button").click(function (evt) {
        $("#parent").load("content.php")
        evt.preventDefault();
    })
})

content.php
<button type="button" id="button">Click me</button>
<img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>" /><!-- loads a random image -->
```

However, the button that reloads the div is inside the `content.php` file (due to the design of the site) which I think it's the root of the problem. The jQuery code works fine if the `#button` is placed outside the `#parent` div, but I need the button to be inside `content.php`.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: because you remove the element and replace it...

Comment: So your solution from the dupe would be `$("#parent").on("click", "#button", function() {});`

Comment: @epascarello Yes, thank you. It works now.